# Getting started on thunderbird extensions

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I have been using Thunderbird for many years now and now I am interested in developing some of my own extensions.  I looked over the documentation on their official website but found little support for getting started at this.  I have some experience with python, perl, php and would like if you can recommend me some getting started materials, a "hello world" for this would be great.

Comment: There's also a demo addon to easily get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Thunderbird/Demo_Addon

Comment: Jonathan, I think it's the only sample extension available which is actually compatible with a recent TB version.

Comment: I tried out the demo example but it wasn't working in Thunderbird, not sure how useful it is as an example. The chat plugin does work however, code available from http://www.xulforum.org/mozcamp2011/ change the .xpi extension to a .zip extension

Answer (score 23):

## **Update 2020**

As of 2020, here is the current documentation:
https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons

---

To build a simple Thunderbird extension in ten minutes look at this tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension

However, the really good tutorial that focuses on creating Mozilla extensions (both Firefox and Thunderbird) is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School

Advanced topics about Thunderbird extensions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos

Some additional info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird

Comment: +1 The one thing I would add is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference

Comment: Oh and http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-release/source/mail/base/ for looking at Thunderbird internals.

Comment: Boy the sheer number of broken links and old, conflicting versions of what documentation there is make for even getting started being a pretty daunting task.

Answer (score 4):

The [extension development forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=19) at Mozilla are a great resource.

Answer (score 2):

### Update: Thunderbird 78

Since version 78 Thunderbird uses new MailExtensions format, legacy extensions 
are no longer supported, most of links posted here before late 2020 are dead.

**Current Mozilla guide** to Thunderbird extensions is here:
https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/mailextensions